# how to upload the image into azure storage blob using angualr2 and typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, azure-blob-storage

I am developing angular 2 application using typescript. in my current project I implemented the functionality for uploading image into storage blob, for that I followed the below link.

http://www.ojdevelops.com/2016/05/end-to-end-image-upload-with-azure.html

The above blog contains the code for angular 1 with javascript but I want the code for angular 2 with typescript.

```
app.controller('UploadCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', function ($scope, Upload) {
$scope.submit = function() {
    if ($scope.form.file.$valid && $scope.file) {
        $scope.upload($scope.file);
    }
};

$scope.upload = function (file) {
    Upload.upload({
        url: 'image/upload',
        data: { file: file }
    }).then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Success');
    }, function (resp) {
        console.log('Error');
    }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '%');
    });
};
```

}]);

Can you please tell me how to convert the above lines of code into angular 2 using typescript.

Comment: What part of converting this code to Angular 2 and TypeScript are you having problems with?

Comment: when I click upload button then I am facing problem. and above lines of code available in my question.

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="UploadCtrl">
    <form name="form">
        <div class="btn btn-primary"
                name="file"
                ngf-select
                ng-model="file"
                ngf-pattern="'image/*'"
                ngf-accept="'image/*'">Select</div>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="submit()">Upload</a>
    </form>           
</div>

Comment: Maybe you can try to show us your current complete angular 2 / typescript code and describe what kind of error you get. In the question, not in a comment.

Comment: I have developed one api controller in that I wrote code for creating the blob container in my storage account and also write the code for uploading the image to it's working every thing fine. but when I click the upload button in my project at that time I don't know how pass the selected image to my upload() method in my api controller like HTTPPost available in the above link what I posted in my question.

Comment: Can you please see the below link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850344/upload-the-image-into-storage-blob-using-typescript-and-angular2

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I achieved the above functionality. for that the answer is available in the below link.

[Upload the image into storage blob using typescript and angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850344/upload-the-image-into-storage-blob-using-typescript-and-angular2/40995996#40995996)

-Pradeep